# How can i get url translations for each language in a wordpress site

Tags: wordpress

in a site made with wordpress, Is there any way that the url is translated for each language?
I use qtranslate plugin.

eg
this is the url of a post in English: 
http://www.mydomain.com/mid-life-career-management/

this is the url in Portuguese:
http://www.mydomain.com/pt/mid-life-career-management/

I want to replace the post title at the url with the translation of Portuguese.

Comment: you can translate : post, category, tag, page but not your domain (i just read the faq and see screen). [qtranslate-slug](http://wordpress.org/plugins/qtranslate-slug/)

Comment: I think you should have a look here http://wpml.org (features http://wpml.org/features/)